# How to take multiple char inputs in a single line in C?

Tags: arrays, input, char, scanf

I want to take multiple inputs in a single line.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    //I am declaring an array     
    char arry[10]; 
    //now i am taking a dynamic input     
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
        scanf("%c",&arry[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Input format:

```
BBBBBBBB
```

but it is taking in like

```
B
B
B
B
B
B
B
```

I have tried %s specifier but it did not work

Answer (score 1):

%s should work.Try this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    char arry[10]; 
    scanf("%s",arry); //make sure to pass the name of the array as it is already a pointer to the array
    return 0;
}
```

Note that scanf stop when it gets whitespace. You can use fgets if you don't wan